# How to get the file's path from file input?

Tags: javascript, file, path

please tell me how to get a full file path from an <input type="file">

i have tried fileinput.value but it shows fakepath.

i have also tried mozFullPath.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons browsers do not allow this, i.e. JavaScript in browser has no access to the File System, however using HTML5 File API, only Firefox provides a mozFullPath property, but if you try to get the value it returns an empty string:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
    console.log(this.files[0].mozFullPath);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SCK5A/

Answer (score 0):

Due to major security reasons, most browsers don't allow getting it so JavaScript when ran in the browser doesn't have access to the user file system. having said that,  the `Firefox` is exceptional and provides the `mozFullPath` property but it will only return an empty string.